# BowerやGruntを使ってHonokaをコンパイルしたい

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, grunt, bower

[windyakin/Honoka](https://github.com/windyakin/Honoka)のv3.3.5-cについてです。

`bootstrap.scss`ファイルをコンパルしようとしたのですが、
bootstrap自体がないようでコンパイルできませんでした。

そこで、
[Bootstrap · The world's most popular mobile-first and responsive front-end framework.](http://getbootstrap.com/)
からブラウザでダウンロードし、`scssディレクトリ`直下に置き、`scssコマンド`でコンパイルしました。

しかし`README.md`をよく読むと上記の手順ではなく、
`Bower`や`Grunt`を使うようになりましたということが書かれております。
（とはいえ具体的な手順については書かれていない）

具体的にどのディレクトリでどのようなコマンドを使えばよいのでしょうか？

bundleであれば、Gemfileがあれば、Gemfileがあるディレクトリで
`bundle install`をするという推測が立ちますが、
`Bower`や`Grunt`でもそのような推測方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bower`, `grunt`は`NodeJS`を使用したCLIです。

[公式ページ](https://nodejs.org/en/)からNodeJSをインストールするか、[nodebrew](https://github.com/hokaccha/nodebrew)で任意のバージョンを利用できます。インストールが終了すると、`npm`コマンドを使用できるようになります。NodeJS-Package-Managerの意です。

```bash
curl -L git.io/nodebrew | perl - setup
nodebrew install-binary v4.2.0
nodebrew use v4.2.0
# use v4.2.0

node -v
# v4.2.0
npm -v
# 2.14.7
```

これで、Honokaの公式リポジトリから、scssのコンパイルが出来るようになります。

```
git clone https://github.com/windyakin/Honoka.git
cd Honoka

npm install grunt-cli --global # `grunt build`コマンドが利用可能に
npm install # `grunt`で使用する依存モジュールを、`Honoka/package.json`を使用して解決する

grunt build # `.scss`のコンパイル。`Honoka/dist` フォルダ内のcss/jsを全て更新する
# ...
# Done, without errors.
```

scssのコンパイルにrubyのscssを使用しますので、これが無い場合は、以下の記事を参考にしてください。

> [Sassを使ってCSSを爆速コーディング！Sassの導入方法と使いかた。 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/saison/items/472ff5a398fceefaa85c)

なお、bowerですが、コンパイル済みのファイルをリリース／ダウンロードするためのコマンドになります。
以下のようにすると、コンパイル済みのファイルを入手できます。

```
npm install bower --global
bower -v
# 1.6.3

bower install "Honoka#3.3.5-c"
# Honoka#3.3.5-c bower_components/Honoka
# └── bootstrap#3.3.5
```